# Converting OS opcodes

Tags: operating-systems, compile, cpu-architecture

I cannot boot Windows 3.1 (by the way, I don't actually mean to boot Windows 3.1, it is just as an example, so don't tailor your response for specifically how to boot windows 3.1) directly on my hardware because the machine code written/compiled/assembled for the CPU at that time is different from the opcodes that my CPU has.

So the only option is to emulate the CPU that the system was intended for.

However, if I wanted to take full advantage of my system (e.g. use all the ram for this OS), then this wouldn't work. Then I would rather want to run it bare metal. But what if it doesn't support my system?

I don't know if this is a thing yet, but is there such a thing as "compiler, but for OSes"? This is my question.

On clarification and details, what I mean by "compiler, but os" is a software that takes in *the machine code of the operating system,* and *the hardware information of what the os is intended to run on*, and *the hardware information of the computer that is about to boot it* and intelligently create a new machine code of the operating system except you can boot it natively on your hardware/cpu (obviously, large modifications and additions to the original code must be changed, for that is why I mentioned it being "intelligent", just like G++ compiler). In other words, if what a normal VM does is interpret os opcodes and run equivalent host machine opcodes, then what I am describing just "pre-interprets it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is there a program that can convert the "opcodes" of any OS to run on any computer?

Comment: The virtual machine will be running as close to the CPU as it can. If your OS can run in a VM then it is by definition going to run as fast as it can on your CPU. Any conversion or compilation will be slower than running on the bare CPU hardware. The first question you have to answer is if it runs in a VM. If it does then you don't have to care about converting or recompiling the program. If it doesn't then you need to find a CPU emulator such as `qemu` which will dynamically recompile as needed.

Comment: Why is it that "If your OS can run in a VM then it is by definition going to run as fast as it can on your CPU"? If what a emulator is doing is interpreting the machine code of the OS to run it on the host system, then wouldn't it be faster to just "pre-interpret" that code and boot from it (compiling it)? How VM beats bare metal I don't understand. Furthermore, running it as virtual machine will not take full advantage of my ram. Still, the question remains unanswered: "is there a program that can as intelligently as a G++ compiler convert original opcode of the os to best suit any purpose?"

Comment: When you say "Any conversion or compilation will be slower than running on the bare CPU hardware.", I assume that you have not completely understood my point, and I apologize for the misconception. What I meant is to "recompile" the opcode of the OS to my own CPU's opcode so that I can boot it natively on my CPU, and not alongside another operating system that runs the VM, because virtualization never beats bare metal.

Comment: if qemu dynamically recompiles as needed, that still not beats having it completely ready to run on a CPU. Say, having ASM interpreted in real time faster or assembled beforehand running faster?

Comment: ok, I don't know why I am getting so much downvotes, maybe it is very obvious, but I am not catching it. can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> is there such a thing as "compiler, but for OSes"?

If all you have is the "*the machine code of the operating system*", then I assume you are referring to the executable binary image of the kernel.

In theory the machine code of one CPU can be translated to the machine code of a CPU of a different architecture. But that typically requires the disassembly (that is, the reverse translation from machine code) of the executable to assembly language. Disassembly facilitates the handling of (memory) addresses for branches, calls, and variables by using symbolic labels (instead of the numeric memory addresses as used in machine code).
Disassembly of an executable binary image is complicated because of the necessity to distinguish data from code. The organization or layout of such binaries is machine and compiler dependent.

Even if you manage to translate the machine code to another machine, you would still be stuck with the code implementing procedures for the original system. The executable binary image of the kernel contains control sequences written specifically for a certain type of hardware. The steps to control and access that hardware, such as a specific peripheral device, are in that code. There is no automated translation or conversion of such procedures for some other hardware system. There are too many nuances to adapt kernel code to a different machine/architecture, so it must be done by hand.

There is no mechanism currently in existence that will "*intelligently create a new machine code*" for you.

---

**Addendum**

> And that the place in which they get these instruction is from the drive.

The CPU (of a conventional digital computer) fetches the (next) instruction from the location specified by the Program Counter register (aka Instruction Pointer). That location would be a memory address.
Instructions are fetched from (main) memory, and not "*from the drive*".
See [Run a computer without RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/857465/run-a-computer-without-ram/857485#857485)

> And my idea is to translate all the code beforehand rather than in real time as I perceive virtualization softwares do.

[You seem to be conflating virtualization and emulation. Learn the differences. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044978/full-emulation-vs-full-virtualization .]

Emulation performs an actual execution path through the executable. The executable image will always have a starting address, i.e. the location of the first instruction (in machine code) to execute. Sequential locations are accessed for subsequent instructions, unless a branch or call or return instruction is "executed", or an interrupt is handled.

Executing (natively or emulating a CPU) an image conveniently identifies the locations that are instructions and data. Locations would be accessed as instructions as those location are executed.
Locations would be accessed for data when referenced by an instruction operand or indirectly through a register.
But emulation will likely only "execute" a portion of the locations in the entire executable image. There will be many locations never referenced or accessed, and hence would not be known to be definitively a location containing an instruction or a datum.
The task of identifying the usage of each and every location can be tedious and complicated.

Are there any assurances that there is no self-modifying code?
Are there any assurances that there is no hidden data mixed in the code, or vice-versa?
Translating an opcode to another instruction set is typically straight-forward. But identifying each instruction versus the data in an executable image cannot always be performed reliably, especially if the instructions have variable length (e.g. Intel x86 instructions).

Translating the instruction set is just the first problem of translating the executable image. Translating the instruction set only represents the change of CPU. Beyond the CPU are the system bus(es) and peripherals. How is the code going to be "translated" to perform different procedures for this different system?

If the executable was a userspace program for a given OS, then hardware details are abstracted by the OS. Such an executable would have minimal hardware dependencies other than the CPU, and the conversion process is greatly simplified.
But since you specified that the executable was the OS (which I interpret to be a kernel), then that is the code that is supposed to implement that hardware abstraction. Such an executable would have many hardware dependencies besides the CPU, and the conversion process is greatly complicated.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough to explain what I mean by "the machine code of the operating system". Maybe my understanding of CPUs are not sufficient enough. All information is from CODE (first edition) by Charles Petzold. So kinda just only understand a little bit of it (you can refer to it to understand what I mean). Because CPUs (as far as I know) change their access in memory (or wherever its booting in that case) and then read whatevers there, and, according to the architecture, does that, which can include adding, subtracting, moving data, etc...

Comment: So my perception is that is how it works. And that the place in which they get these instruction is from the drive. And if the instruction is written for some other CPU but runs on the current, then it will produce not the best results. so thinking of some way to translate that code from one system to another is how I think emulators work. And my idea is to translate all the code beforehand rather than in real time as I perceive virtualization softwares do.

Comment: FYI Unlike you, my "*understanding of CPUs*" is not from just one book. I've written code and kernels for numerous computer architectures, many that you never heard of (e.g. some predate the x86 PC).

Comment: Okay, I looked up what you're using as a "reference" book. It seems to be for non-technical readers. Parts of my answer therefore may not be comprehensible to you. E.G. I've noticed numerous posts on this site that think assembly language is the same as machine language, but it's not. Jean Sammet explained all the differences in "Programming Languages"; my copy is 40+ years old.