# Is it possible to run Windows 98 SE from L3 cache with no RAM installed?

Tags: memory, windows-98, cpu-cache

Modern CPUs can have L3 cache in the range of tens of megabytes (e.g. 24MB). W98SE requires at least 16MB of RAM to run (24MB recommended). Is it possible to use the L3 cache as RAM, without any external RAM attached?

Comment: assuming you can get a motherboard to function without installed memory?

Comment: Very related to your question (but didn't show up on the sidebar): http://superuser.com/questions/570961/can-we-run-linux-in-something-faster-than-ram

Comment: @Moab You mean a BIOS, and yes.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, no.

While your CPU may have that L1/2/3 cache available, your OS will expect it to be used only for the CPU. The OS is going to want actual memory, in the form of RAM.

If you are gung-ho about using Windows 98, do yourself two favours:

1. Get Windows 98 SE - it works much nicer in my experience
2. Run it in a Virtual Machine. Virtualbox is free, open source, and available on almost every major platform.

Comment: There isn't a tag for Windows 98 SE in case you didn't know. And I mentioned Windows 98 SE both in the post and in the title.

Comment: Correct answer, but wrong reason.  Twice you mention the OS, but that is not the issue.  If the OS *"expected"* something or is *"going to want"* something, then since the OS is software. the OS could be rewritten to expect or want an alternative.  Rather it's a hardware implementation that dedicates the CPU cache as a cache rather than *byte addressable*, random access memory.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Motherboards require memory to function.  Cache memory cannot be used as RAM.

Comment: Good point about motherboards requiring memory to function... But that's not the CPU.

Comment: Actually it's the CPU that requires memory.  The RAM has to exist for the CPU; it doesn't matter where it's installed.   If you consider something not x86, there are SBCs that have no memory chips because the RAM is integrated with the CPU in one IC package.  Your third sentence is the correct reason.

Comment: Do you have any proof that x86 cache cannot, under any circumstances, be used as RAM?

Comment: @SoniEx2 yes.  basic computer architecture.

Comment: Cache **can be used as RAM** on x86 and many architectures: [Cache-as-Ram (no fill mode) Executable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27699197/995714), [CAR: Using Cache as RAM in LinuxBIOS](https://www.coreboot.org/data/yhlu/cache_as_ram_lb_09142006.pdf), [A Framework for Using Processor Cache as RAM (CAR)](https://www.coreboot.org/images/6/6c/LBCar.pdf)